# MySQL update output deleted

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a row and get its contents at the same time.
I am using the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET number=number+1 OUTPUT DELETED.* WHERE ID=?
```

I could do this in 2 queries, but I want to keep things atomic to avoid a race condition.

Comment: is there a problem with this query, then? P.S. If you used a transaction round 2 queries it would effectively be atomic.

Comment: @ADyson this query doesn't work with mySQL as it doesn't support it, I'll look into transactions thank you!

Comment: Just quickly going over it I have a quick question on it, if I start a transaction and before its closed another query is inputted and then the transaction is rollbacked, wouldn't that cause the inputted query to also be rolled back?

Comment: no because the transaction only rolls back what's done within it. That's the entire point. If the 2nd query was done outside a transaction, or within the context of a different transaction (even if it's same piece of code being used, the context is the context in which it's _executed_, so two different executions of the same code are different transaction contexts) then a rollback of the 1st transaction would not affect it.

Comment: AFAICT, MySQL 8.0 doesn't support `OUTPUT DELETED.*` as part of its syntax for an [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) statement.  Which DBMS does support the notation?

Comment: Ended up just adding a boolean collumn to see if it's being used. Thanks for the suggestions though!