# How can I delete and get the row data in an atomic way?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I have single use keys stored in a table column. I have a table which contains only unique keys which, once read and sent, must be deleted from table using an **atomic** operation.

How can I accomplish this?

I need to use Node.js in asynchronous way; it is cumbersome to run two queries(`select`, and `delete`) for each request using transactions.

I wish that `Delete` returned the key as well... that'd have been easiest.

MySQL version: 5.5.54

Comment: @Dharman innodb

Comment: Is there any possibility for you to use another DB type e.g. MariaDB 10 or are you stuck with MySQL 5?

Comment: @Dharman cant change from mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a Stored Procedure to do the `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` and `DELETE` in a single transaction and returning the `SELECT` results.  Then perform a single `CALL` from your client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of [MySQL update output deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44409872/1839439) which has no answer either.
The thing is that MySQL has not implemented such syntax yet. It is available in other DBs, but in MySQL you are most likely stuck with `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE; DELETE ...` inside of a transaction. I am afraid that in MySQL you might not have any better option yet.

Some other links:

- [In MariaDB 10.0.5 it is possible to return values from
  DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097320/1839439)
- [OUTPUT
  Clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819632/1839439)
- [In
  mysql can I return deleted rows after a
  deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33115526/1839439)

Comment: If you find that any of the links I provided are either answering your question or this is a direct duplicate of any of them we can close this question as a duplicate instead.